# apple mail don't get my mail after a while

Tags: macos, email, imap, apple-mail

I use Apple Mail for my default email reader and it works fine (I set IMAP for my email reader setting) but from a week ago it's stopped getting my mail. I still can send mail to other people but can't get my mail from Apple Mail reader!  Does any one have idea what the problem is?

p.s: If I mail to my email acount from Apple Mail it gets the mail but if others mail me I don't get them.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me -
I was using all the right stuff, but Apple Mail has an additional menu
item called Online Status which I needed to toggle. When I did that, my
email came in.

Comment: you mean show online buddy status? or something else?

Comment: There is an option in Apple Mail which allows you to toggle your "Online Status"

Comment: I can't fine what you said can you pls tell where shoud I go to find this setting?