# Can't connect to Gmail server via Mail.app in Mac OS X 10.6.3

Tags: macos, gmail, apple-mail

I've added my gmail account to Mail.app

It worked find in previous days, and downloaded thousands of previous mails.

But now, it can't connect to gmail server for days.

What's the matter here?

Here is my config in account setting:

```
Account Type: Gmail IMAP
Email Address: xxx@gmail.com
Incoming Mail Server: imap.gmail.com
User Name: xxx@gmail.com
Password: xxxxxx
```

And also, is there any means that I can view the transaction log of Mail.app? Maybe there I can find more information.

Comment: I have a same problem, And can't solve it you can see : http://superuser.com/questions/143318/apple-mail-dont-get-my-mail-after-a-while

Comment: Does webmail access still work? This recent question http://superuser.com/questions/146913/can-i-see-the-smtp-session-log-when-mail-app-connects-to-an-smpt-server is about SMTP access, but it talks about logging which applies equally well to IMAP servers.

Comment: webmail works fine, only IMAP doesn't work

Comment: What does the "Window -> Connection Doctor" show?

Answer (score 1):

I've changed from IMAP to POP, and now it works.

The trick here is that you can't specify your gmail address when adding a new account, in that way, Mail.app will automatically use IMAP for your gmail account.

Just use another address, and in the manual setting, set up the gmail POP server.

Comment: Did you disable IMAP somehow? Personally, I always prefer IMAP to POP.  Instructions for enabling gmail IMAP here: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77695

Comment: Do you not have IMAP enabled on your account? Always use IMAP when possible. It's security is better and if you delete an email from Mail.app, it will also delete it from the server and your other devices (iPhone, etc.) Consider reading this: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77695

Comment: You may want to mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Thorough explanation for setup of IMAP GMail in Mail.app: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77695